# Can I make the entire "Table 1" clickable as a reference in Latex?

Tags: latex

In my document, I'm using the label function to label tables and figures:

```
\label{}
```

Then I use the `\ref{}` function to refer to the table or figure. in my text.

The problem that I have is that in my text I write this:

```
As can be seen in Table \ref{table1}.
```

It will output my text as:

```
As can be seen in Table 1.
```

However only the number "1" is clickable and leads up to the table. I want the "Table" part to be clickable as well, so you can click on any part of "Table 1" and get referred up to the table.

I've tried different ways by using `\phantomsection\label{}` and then `\hyperref[]{}`, but this doesn't output the table or figure number dynamically.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `\autoref`.

`\autoref` creates a reference with text depending on the type.

A picture will tell more then thousand words:

[image]

Example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\textbackslash ref to the Figure \ref{fig:example}

\textbackslash autoref to the  \autoref{fig:example}

\textbackslash nameref to the figure \nameref{fig:example}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\label{fig:example}Example image}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

To change the text inserted by `\autoref` for e.g. a table:

```
\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{bettertablename}
```

See the `hyperref` manual for all options.